# How to call choice name instead of value in Shiny?

Tags: r, input, shiny, output, shinydashboard

I'm working on a dashboard where sometimes I need to call the input's choice name and other times it's value, but I only know how to get the latter. Is there a way to call the first one?

Here is a minimum reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    header = dashboardHeader(),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = dashboardBody(
        selectInput(
            "input",
            h5("The output should give the choice name instead of it's value"),
            choices=c(
                "Name 1" = 1,
                "Name 2" = 2,
                "Name 3" = 3
            )
        ),
        textOutput("output")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$output <- renderPrint({paste(input$input)})  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it is easiest to create a `data.frame` with the choices and the corresponding names in advance, and use that to look up the name of the selected input. A working example is given below, hope this helps!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

choices_df = data.frame(
  names = c('Name 1', 'Name 2', 'Name 3'),
  id = seq(3)
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
  body = dashboardBody(
    selectInput(
      "input",
      h5("The output should give the choice name instead of it's value"),
      choices= setNames(choices_df$id,choices_df$names)
    ),
    textOutput("output")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$output <- renderPrint({paste(choices_df$names[choices_df$id==input$input])})  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```